# Jmeter is not recording script if there is any German character in parameter. Any Solution?

Tags: jmeter, special-characters, performance-testing, siebel

I am trying to record a scenario in which a list contains a word with German special characters (ä,ö,ü). But Jmeter is unable to record that script. Is there any solution available? Regarding HTTPS request encoding or something else?

[Browser Window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RNiJd.png)

[Jmeter Recording](https://i.stack.imgur.com/punIb.png)

Comment: whicj version are you using ?

Comment: can you show the broken request ? Try export as curl in firefox or chrome. Thanks

Comment: Hi @UBIKLOADPACK, I'm using Jmeter version 4 r1823414.

Comment: As Im new to Jmeter so can you guide me how to export as curl?

Comment: While recording scenario if there is any german characteer filled in any input field then no sampler is getting recorded in Jmeter and it becomes non-responsive as well.

Comment: To export as curl, it has no relation with JMeter, so in your browser , open Developer Tools, select network, hit the URL that triggers the issue , the URL will appear in panel, right click on URL and select export as Curl

Answer (score 0):

I cannot reproduce your issue using latest JMeter 5.0 (be aware that [according to JMeter Best Practices you should be always using the latest version of JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#use_latest_version) which is available at [JMeter Downloads](https://jmeter.apache.org/download_jmeter.cgi) page)

[image]

You can try adding the next line to *system.properties* file:

```
file.encoding=UTF-8
```

---

Also be aware that there is an alternative way of recording a JMeter test - using [JMeter Chrome Extension](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/the-new-blazeMeter-chrome-extension-v4-easily-script-jmeter-and-selenium), in this case you will not have to worry about proxies, SSL certificates, etc. so given you can execute the request in your browser - it will be captured and converted into JMeter .jmx test script.

Comment: I have tried the above suggestion, adding file encoding property, but still its not recording my values. I have edited my question and added two screenshots for detailed information. Can you have a look pls. ?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding utf-8 as content encoding for HTTP request in http request defaults
We had similar problems, when parameters containing german letters were not recognized by API, ant this solved it..